# How do I link multiple Word documents to a centralized header and footer

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office-2010, templates, headers

In our company we have recently changed our trading name and now all templates have to be changed with a new header and footer. We have over 1000 documents that need to be changed manually one by one with this new style. As you can imagine we are not keen on doing this.

Now that we are at it we are looking for a way to make this easier in the future so that we can change a header or footer in one place and all documents change with it. Is it possible to make a word document rely on a single, centralized, template? We are using different versions of office throughout the company but mostly 2007 and 2010.

This seems a common problem and I can imagine it having a simple solution but my journey on the google has not brought me much result.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the header and footers text only? Or do they include an image which needs to be changed?

Comment: They also contain an image of the logo (which is actually the thing we need to change right now)

Answer (score 2):

As far as changing what currently exists, I've used [VBA Find & Replace](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/vba_find_and_replace.html) to change the text in multiple files when our company name changed. It doesn't change images though. I haven't found a way to do that yet.

Moving forward, to make the documents change from a central document, here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1946536/1141581) from the sister site, StackOverflow, which very closely answers your question.